# Oracle date format issue

Tags: oracle, date

I'm trying to export/import data in .csv format using SQLDeveloper.  The source and destination databases are Oracle 11g.  I'm having a hard time with the date formats.  In the exported .csv, I see dates like:

```
31-AUG-09 11.54.00.000000000 AM
```

I'm trying to figure out the appropriate format string, but I don't know what the last element is before the meridian indicator (AM/PM).  Here's the format string I have.

```
'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.??????????? AM'
```

What should take the place of the question marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these values are always `00000000000`, then `???????????` could be just fine, in case you use `DATE`.

If you want to convert those `0`s, you need to use a `TIMESTAMP` and `FF9`:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP( '31-AUG-09 11.54.00.000000000 AM',
                     'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF9 AM' )
FROM dual
```

You have another problem though: Use `MI` instead of `MM`, since `MM` is month and can not be used twice.

Comment: The second MM was a typo.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FF9` to represent the fractional seconds part.